# gtk textview background yellow color?

Tags: colors, background, textview, gtk

first of all i'm actually lame at gtk programming and i'm just building some simple examples so far, and I have this:

```
GdkColor color;

gtk_widget_realize(window);

gtk_style_lookup_color(gtk_widget_get_style(window), "bg_color", &color);
gtk_widget_modify_base(data->text, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```

which makes my textview gray, just like the default background of an empty window. but now i'm trying to change it to yellow and i can't figure out how to do that, i've read some other way to do it which is not like the one that im using, but it doesn't even work.
yes, i suck. but any help would be grateful!
btw i'm programming in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, this is just about initializing a GdkColor and not really a problem with the textview? Try something like this

```
if (!gdk_color_parse ("yellow", &color)) {
    g_print ("Failed to parse color\n");
} else {
    gtk_widget_modify_base (data->text, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
}
```

You can also use rgb hex values (like `"#FFFF00"`) instead of colour names.